# Open a Docker Apache and PHP stack in Browser

Tags: apache, docker, configuration, ip

I am a Docker rookie who is stuck in configuration. I just wanted to build a docker Apache and PHP Stack with this guide:
[Apache and PHP on Docker](https://writing.pupius.co.uk/apache-and-php-on-docker-44faef716150).
All seems worked except the problem that i don't know how to connect to my created docker container via browser IP/URL. Normally in Apache without Docker you just configure your /etc/hosts file with a ServerName and connect to it.

What is the solution with Docker?

Answer (score 1):

When you run docker, you need to connect the host port with the apache port running inside your container.

This is done by adding `-p 8000:80` where 8000 is your local port and 80 is the docker container port.

If you then connect to `localhost:8000` you should see the response from apache in your docker container.